# ASP.Net Ajax Control Toolkit "UpdatePanelAnimationExtender" breaking jQuery focus() onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following update panel with a text field limited to 9 characters only accepting numbers.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelsearchusers" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="formfieldarea">
            <div id="searchfield1" class="searchfieldbox">
                <asp:Label ID="USIDSearchlbl" runat="server" Text="USID: " CssClass="formlabel" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="USIDSearchBox" runat="server" MaxLength="9" />
                <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="USIDSearchBox" ValidChars="0123456789" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="USIDsearchbutton" runat="server" ImageUrl="/tissuebank/images/searchButton.png" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="search1_Click" CssClass="searchbutton" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>{output from search}</div>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the following JavaScript which will automatically trigger the search button if the number of characters reaches 9.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function setupUSIDFocus() {
        $('#<%=USIDSearchBox.ClientID %>').focus().keyup(function () { 
           if ($(this).val().length == 9) { 
                $('.searchbutton').first().click(); 
           } 
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () { setupUSIDFocus(); });
 </script>
```

If I have the code as above this works fine and loads with the focus being on the element `USIDSearchBox` as I intended, however when the update panel is updated but the event is no longer assigned to the box and the focus is lost. To fix this I added an ASP.Net Ajax control `UpdatePanelAnimationExtender` so that the focus and events are reassigned when the request is complete.

```
  <AjaxControlToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="upae" runat="server" TargetControlID="updatePanelsearchusers">
      <Animations>
          <OnUpdated>
              <Sequence>
                  <Parallel duration="0">
                      <ScriptAction Script="setupUSIDFocus();" />   
                  </Parallel>             
              </Sequence>
          </OnUpdated>
      </Animations>        
  </AjaxControlToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

And indeed this does reset the focus and the `keyup` event but for some reason the element does not get focus when the page is first loaded. Though the `keyup` event is still attached `onload` I am just missing the focus being on the `USIDSearchBox` field. If I remove the `UpdatePanelAnimationExtender` then I get the focus back on load, so it must be something to do with this control.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the focus `onload` of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use 'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript' in 'search1_Click' to call the jQuery function after ajax update:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"myscript","setupUSIDFocus();",true);
```

Comment: Brilliant I removed the UpdatePanelAnimationExtended and added the registerStartupScript to Page_Load now it is working completely for my use case. Thank you.